# I'd like to run a loop, but change 2 variables each instance

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to edit a VBA code.  I customized it for my needs, but it is currently repeating the same process over 20 times, and I have basically entered the code 20 times and changed the variables.

I will likely have up to 100 instances, and don't want to manually do this.  How can I edit this code so that it runs 100 times while changing the variables?

As you see, I have included the same code twice with slight changes.  I would need to change the ticker and range for each iteration, and Also, the destination Range would need to move 1 column over each time.

By the way, this is for pulling yahoo finance stock info.

```
Sub Data_Get()
'
' Data_Get Macro
'
Dim ticker1, ticker2, ticker3 As String, sday, smonth, syear, eday, emonth, eyear As Long

ticker1 = Range("L1")
ticker2 = Range("L2")
ticker3 = Range("L3")

sday = Day(Range("L4"))
smonth = Month(Range("L4")) - 1
syear = Year(Range("L4"))
eday = Day(Range("L5"))
emonth = Month(Range("L5")) - 1
eyear = Year(Range("L5"))

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ticker1 & "&d=" & emonth & "&e=" & eday & "&f=" & eyear & "&g=d&a=" & smonth & "&b=" & sday & "&c=" & syear & "&ignore=.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "data"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ticker2 & "&d=" & emonth & "&e=" & eday & "&f=" & eyear & "&g=d&a=" & smonth & "&b=" & sday & "&c=" & syear & "&ignore=.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$C$1"))
    .Name = "data2"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like the following ...

```
Dim i as long, nIter as long
' calculate the number iterations here, using your calcuation
nIter = 100

' do the same job repeatedly
for iLoop = 1 to nIter

' put the code you want to repeat in here
' if you want to move down in a range every iteration, one possible way is as follows...
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ticker1 & _
      "&d=" & emonth & "&e=" & eday & "&f=" & eyear & "&g=d&a=" & smonth & _
      "&b=" & sday & "&c=" & syear & "&ignore=.csv" _
      , Destination:=Range("$A$1").Offset(iLoop-1,0))

next iLoop
```

Comment: Thank you!  So much!  I have made this work, but my only last problem is that I have info in Row 1, over each list, but when I run this, it creates new columns, and shifts the things in the top row over.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Take a look at the [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839455.aspx). I think you should be using `xlInsertEntireRows` instead of `xlInsertDeleteCells`